# Launch PostgreSQL on Login/Startup

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm on OS X and have installed PostgreSQL via homebrew. Now whenever I want to start development I need to run the following command to start PostgreSQL.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

I've tried a few different links I've found to try to set this up so when I login to my machine PostgreSQL starts automatically. However, with the different installation methods I can't seem to find one that works.

I also tried using Automator to get it to launch. But, even those resources don't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ brew info postgresql
...
To have launchd start postgresql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load postgresql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I didn't think of looking there.